# Configure winbind to check multiple attributes in AD?

Tags: redhat, authentication, winbind

I have winbind up and running and it is working well for authentication.

When a user is prompted at logon to provide credentials what AD attribute is username checked against? Is it name? sAMAccountName? CN?

The follow-up to this is can I make a change to winbind either via authconfig or smb.conf to allow two possible matches? E.g., I want to have user be able to provide at logon either ID number (currently working) and/or email username (attribute is mailnickname in AD)

**EDIT:** Is this not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Active Directory stores this information in LDAP accessible databases.
LDAP query filter `"(|(idnumber=%s)(mailnickname =%s))"`.
Unknown if Samba/Winbind allow use of RFC2254 query filters.

Comment: Thanks for the response... not sure what variable to change/add to smb.conf or pam.d though to add the filter.